# master had recent pushes 56 seconds ago

Tags: git, github

I'm new to Github. I don't know why this message is shown in the `main` branch. I have just copied the  commands

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m "Add existing project files to Git"
git remote add origin https://github.com/cameronmcnz/example-website.git
git push -u -f origin master
```

After this when I go to my Github account I recieve this compare & pull request message!

Does anyone know why it is showing me this?

[image: this is the screenshot of message]

Comment: You're not using pull requests so just ignore it and move on. You might need to read my https://www.biteinteractive.com/of-git-and-github-master-and-main/

Answer (score 2):

It is simple, when you do `git init` it intializes a local folder `.git/` which has `master` branch by default.

Any respository in github though has `main` as its default branch, not `master`. So when you commit something locally and push that to Github, it thinks you have a branch that you want to merge with the `main` branch in the future, i.e why it proposes to generates a pull request to compare the changes in the `main` branch and the `master` branch and why you get that "compare and pull request" message.

The request here means someone (in this case you) has to review the changes and approve them, so that they can be merged into the `main` branch.

Comment: Short version is that GitHub decided to perenially confuse beginners by using a non-default default.

Comment: it's different because `git` and `github` are intially different they have different roles to play , also `git` is maintained by `Linux`, while `GitHub` is maintained by `Microsoft` , So you can make the sense to why there is a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the git link [link](https://github.com/cameronmcnz/example-website.git) is incorrect. It should be your git url. Secondly, this message appears when a new change is pushed to git. It shows that a branch (other than main) has made some changes and a pull request to merge the changes into main can be created.